# matplotlib set color, style in oo fashion

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can set the color and style of a plot in matplotlib in the following way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3], 'r-')
plt.show()
```

This works, but:

1. I can only use the colors specified by one character, like 'r', 'k', etc. It would be better to be able to use the HTML color names, which matplotlib accepts.
2. I may have to prepare in advance the string that will be passed, doing something like

   ```
   fmt = 'r' + '_'
   ```

So I would like to have commands of the type:

```
obj.set_color('Aquamarine')
obj.set_style('-')
```

I could not find a way to do this.

Answer (score 6):

You have all the possible options in the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html#controlling-line-properties).

So you can either provide all the options to the plot function:

```
plt.plot([1,2,3], [5,6,7], color='#FF4455', linestyle='--')
```

or you can just plot and the plot function will return a list of `Artist`s it created (in this case just one line). After that you can set the properties on that particular line.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
lines = ax.plot([1,2,3], [5,6,7])
line = lines[0]
line.set_color('#994455')
line.set_linestyle('--')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just set the colour and line style separately:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3], color="r", ls="-")
plt.show()
```

From the docs of plot:

> In addition, you can specify colors in many weird and
>       wonderful ways, including full names (`'green'`), hex
>       strings (`'#008000'`), RGB or RGBA tuples (`(0,1,0,1)`) or
>       grayscale intensities as a string (`'0.8'`).  Of these, the
>       string specifications can be used in place of a `fmt` group,
>       but the tuple forms can be used only as `kwargs`.

So just add arguments to accept the color and line style you want

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dictionary to store the keyword arguments used in a call to `plt.plot`:

```
fmt = { 'color': 'red', 'linestyle' : '--'}
x = np.arange(10)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y,**fmt)
```

See: [Unpacking Argument Lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) in the Python docs.